# Airline pays only part of replacement flight

Tags: air-travel, airlines, cancellations, passenger-rights, wizz-air

I had a flight in December that was cancelled because of snow storm (EU flight, from Budapest to Iceland). The Wizz Air's next available flight was in approximately 7 days from the day I was supposed to be flying (they had other flights earlier but they were all fully booked). Therefore, I decided to buy a ticket from another company for a flight the next day (same origin and destination city) and ask for a refund from Wizz later. I was only asking for a refund of the replacement flight ticket, not the 250 EUR compensation since the cancellation was caused by weather conditions.

Recently they got back to me, however, they refused to pay the full flight price of about ~600-700 EUR (300k HUF) and instead only offered seemingly random value of 150 EUR. According to [1] though, I would think I have right to be fully reimbursed or not at all. Considering that they offered *something*, I'm guessing they agree I have the right to reimbursement and so I would expect the full price to be covered.

**Can an airline reimburse only part of my replacement flight and not the whole ticket that I had to buy because my original flight was cancelled?** How come they are offering only 150 EUR reimbursement, is there some rule that allows them to only reimburse part of the costs?

Thanks

[1] https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#reimbursement-cancellation-1

Comment: How much did you pay for the original flight? If you cancel and book your own tickets you are entitled to a full refund of the original price but not necessarily  replacement ticket that you buy on your own. The airline is going to drag their feet on that one since its somewhat up to interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The original price was approximately 50-60 EUR, they actually refunded that automatically in form of a voucher without consulting with me whether I want it. As for the cancellation, I didn't cancel my flight, it was them who cancelled it.